# Create new User as current User Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am not good at English. I have a problem with creating oracle database user in Oracle Server 11g.
I have a database named ‘ABC’ on my Server with login account named ‘test1’, now I want to create new user named 'test2' who can connect to ‘ABC’ database as user 'test1'. How can I do that?
Please help me. Thank You!

Comment: Do you really want 'test2' to login as 'test1'?  Wouldn't that just mean that you logged in as 'test1'?

Comment: Yes, I want 'test2' can login as 'test1';

Comment: Yes, I want 'test2' can login as 'test1'; I mean that two or more users can connect to one Database named 'ABC', Can I do that?